# Powershell - Object

Tags: powershell

This is a simple one, but my brain has me not thinking correctly :/

Anywho, I have a script that runs that creates a user in ShareFile which pulls a group name and ID - I can get this working no issues along with getting the ids that I want, however I need to turn this into a variable as such to be used throughout.
Existing Variables:

```
$projectname = M001
$rbacgg = "RBACGG_$($projectcode)_STD-USERS"
```

Script below:

`$group = Send-SfRequest $sfClient -Method Get -Entity Groups | Select-Object -Property Name,id`

This returns the following

```
Name                   Id                                  
----                   --                                  
RBACGG_M000_PWR-USERS  g205d542-cd65-4175-94a9-1f2721e6fe8a
RBACGG_M000_STD-USERS  gfe7d256-2f88-4d93-9be4-7ffac7bcfec0
RBACGG_M001_STD-USERS  g02c3ada-c84e-43e5-a6fc-72612d02fdd6
RBACGG_M002_ROY-MORGAN g91a15ee-b433-4ef3-a239-42a9baba00ce
RBACGG_M002_STD-USERS  g49e38e9-211d-434a-9e31-f2225daa1c67
RBACGG_M003_STD-USERS  gd42c025-2797-432c-9b56-cdf3a01e6601
RBACGG_M004_STD-USERS  g8272af9-9a97-4cfa-beca-1a53a75cf201
RBACGG_M005_STD-USERS  gadeaf09-be43-4a19-8e55-ccac0fb26007
RBACGG_M006_STD-USERS  gab033f4-5cac-4cf9-87ff-c9c88c84d2e1
RBACGG_M007_STD-USERS  ge125507-df6d-42f6-b651-906a74115a89
```

My next command is as follows

`Send-SfRequest $sfClient -Method POST -Entity Groups -Id '$id' -Navigation Contacts -BodyText '[{"Email":"$emailaddress"}]'`

I need to pop in an if statement or similar that does the following:
If $rbacgg = RBACGG_M000_STD-USERS then match it with a group Name above and pull the ID.

That ID will then be used in the command just above.

Comment: `$group |Where-Object name -eq $rbacgg |ForEach-Object { Send-SfRequest $sfClient -Method POST -Entity Groups -Id $_.id -Navigation Contacts -BodyText '[{"Email":"$emailaddress"}]' }`

Comment: If iRon's comment answered your question feel free to post it as an answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=To%20encourage%20people%20to%20do,of%20the%20Ask%20Question%20page.)